# Hive: extracting milliseconds from interval_day_time?

Tags: hive, milliseconds

I'd like to get millisecond precision from some datetime deltas I have. There's no millisecond() function that I see for Hive.

Consider this:

```
with t as (
    select (CAST(1481652239798 AS TIMESTAMP) - CAST(1481652228576 as timestamp)) 
    as delta
) 
select delta from t;

0 00:00:11.222000000
```

I can work with that, if I could convert that output into a string and extract the part following the period.

```
with t as (
    select (CAST(1481652239798 AS TIMESTAMP) - CAST(1481652228576 as timestamp)) 
    as delta
) 
select instr(delta, '.') from t

11 -- correct index of '.'
```

So instr() treats delta as a string, but I can't substring it:

```
with t as (
    select (CAST(1481652239798 AS TIMESTAMP) - CAST(1481652228576 as timestamp)) 
    as delta
) 
select substr(delta, 11) from t; -- directly supplying instr() leads to a different bug with parsing the query syntax

No matching method for class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFSubstr with (interval_day_time, int)
```

Any workarounds?

Comment: I don't know hive, but: can't you save it as string to new variable, then slice?

Comment: This is insane. You start with numbers whose unit is a **number of milliseconds** since UNIX epoch, then you convert these to Timestamps, then you compute a time difference, then you want to get back to milliseconds. Why don't you just substract your original numbers, and be happy ever after?!?

Comment: What exactly you're trying to is beyond me.  But even though Hive should allow an implicit cast from a timestamp to a string ([Documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-AllowedImplicitConversions)), apparently it's not for that function. I hate implicit casts for this reason.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter
Whoops, people on my team pointed out the same thing. When I threw the timestamp numbers into date -d@, I didn't notice they were from the year 48921. I just quickly thought they were in seconds, not millis already.

e: I was wondering how second-precision timestamps could have millis in the difference...

Answer (score 0):

If you cast the `timestamp` object to `double` it preserves the milliseconds part.

So try the following:

```
with t as (
    select CAST(1481652239798 AS TIMESTAMP) as ts1,  
           CAST(1481652228576 as timestamp) as ts2             
) 
select ts1,
       ts2,
       (ts1-ts2) as delta, 
       floor((CAST(ts1 AS double)-CAST(ts2 as double))*1000) as delta_ms
from t
```